# Python/Raspberry Pi guaranty about interrupt response time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, real-time, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I want to use an RPi to control some water pumps. My question is, what kind of guaranties can I make about the "real timeness"? I have a pump filling a container, and when a sensor signals the RPi that it is full the pump should turn off. How much extra room in the container needs to be left for the worst case response time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a theoretical perspective, Python running as a userspace process on a Linux kernel makes no realtime guarantees whatsoever.

In practice, interrupt response times will usually be in the low millisecond range. In all probability, the pump will take considerably longer to shut off than the rPi will take to respond.

Comment: Interesting. Are real programs usually implemented in kernalspace then?

Comment: These days, realtime tasks are typically implemented on microcontrollers, or on systems running a realtime OS (e.g, VXWorks). There are ways to get real-time scheduling on Linux as well, but I'm not sure they're available on the RPi, and in any case Python may not be real-time compliant either.

Comment: Would that make something like an Arduino more suitable for controlling pumps using sensors?

Comment: Absolutely, yes. A microcontroller (like the AVR in an Arduino board) is much better suited for this sort of task.

Comment: Alright. They're actually a lot cheaper than I thought. Going to miss my Python though...